# Difference between obj.split() and obj

Tags: python

When I type this code:

```
phrase = 'I love my life'
phrase = phrase.split()
phrase.remove('I')
phrase
```

I got this result as expected:

```
['love', 'my', 'life']
```

However, when I try to make it more concise:

```
phrase = 'I love my life'
phrase.split().remove('I')
phrase
```

I have this unexpected result:

```
'I love my life'
```

It's strange, what is the difference between **phrase = phrase.split()** and this object **phrase.split()**?  When we type type(phrase.split()), it's a list as well.

So what is the difference between them? I didn't understand the error, someone could explain to me?

Comment: You never reassign `phrase` in the second case.

Comment: @Julien but why do I need to?

Comment: @Julien both aren't the same object?

Comment: @Julien yes, why do we need to reassign? for me both are the same list object.

Comment: @user804406 Look at the docs for `str.split`, it doesn’t mutate/modify the original list.

Comment: `.split()` returns a list, it does not mutate the original string. It would not make sense to mutate a string to a list in-place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**str.split()**

> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter
> string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus,
> the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is not
> specified or -1, then there is no limit on the number of splits (all
> possible splits are made)...

strings are immutable in python. the above taken from python docs.org.
in the code below, first case:

```
phrase = 'I love my life'   
phrase = phrase.split()
phrase.remove('I')
```

**at line 1**: phrase a var name binded to string object with the value "I love my life".

**at line 2**: phrase a var name binded to a list object! he is no more pointing to the previous string, cos we have assign it to point to new py object.

**at line 3** : `list.remove()` works on the same list, updating it if the object you want to remove are exist in the list.

**code snippet 2**

```
phrase = 'I love my life'
phrase.split().remove('I')
```

**at line 1**: phrase a var name binded to string object with the value "I love my life".

**at line 2**: since string are immutables, the interpreter do the work for you and get the job done, but the result of this expression was not assigned to any var name! if you want to get the same behavior you need to assign the result to phrase var name or pythonly speaking, rebinding the phrase var name.

see the links below for further reading

[list.remove](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20split#str.split)

[str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20split#str.split)

Comment: @user804406 if my answer was useful. i will be glad if you accept it (push th V nearby)! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, `phrase.split()` itself does nothing because you didn't assign it to a variable. However, even if you did `phrase = phrase.split().remove('I')`, it still wouldn't work because the `.remove('I')` doesn't return anything to the variable `phrase`. Basically, `.split()` returns a list, only if you assign it to a variable and `.remove('I')` mutates the lists itself and return `None` if you assign that to a variable.